# Facebook - Cannot get infinate expiry token for page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, token

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension#extendingpagetokens

After reading through this documentation I was under the impression that I could get a token that never expired if I requested a short lived access token with the scope manage_pages however when I follow the documentation and use the following to get an extended token:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Then I place the token inside of the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

I get the following response:

[image]

The closest I've found to what I'm doing is this: [How do you get long-lived access tokens from the Facebook Graph API (server-side auth)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355283/how-do-you-get-long-lived-access-tokens-from-the-facebook-graph-api-server-side)

Perhapse is it another scope they requested that I didn't?

Also another thing I noticed is that due to not being a live app these are the "permissions" I have, of which manage_pages isn't one. However how could any new product work if the app needs to exist before it can function????

[image]

any and all help appreciated

Comment: _“However how could any new product work if the app needs to exist before it can function?”_ - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921, duh.

Comment: Which `{short-lived-token}` did you use in the API call?

Comment: maybe this helps you: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: CBroe ok so the issue isn't to do with that I'm still in development mode it looks like. ---- 

@luschn that looks somewhat promising, however with the current lockdown of the graph api endpoint I am unable to access /PAGE-ID?fields=access_token. Is the Page Access Token flow shown on that page different than from the one shown here?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension#extendingpagetokens

Comment: damn that downvote is harsh :( really thought I covered my bases with this post, wonder what I did to get that reaction from some people.

Comment: why are you unable to access the page token? works fine for me. if you get the error that it´s currently disabled, just try with a new app.

Comment: I am able to get a page token via the documentations implementation, however it’s got an expiry. The use case is an server side call to get data that I will use to make a Facebook latest reviews component. The token is never sent to the client so it’s basically a secret key. For this reason having to renew it every 2 months is just adding a new task that really doesn’t need to exist.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) get your short-lived access token.
2. Go to [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/), debug your short-lived access token from Step1, click the extend button at the bottom, you will get a long-lived token
3. Go to [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) again, now use your long-lived token from Step2, request path `/me/accounts`, find the corresponding token for your target page in response data
4. to make sure it is the never expire token you need, debug it by [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/)

Ref: https://sujipthapa.co/blog/generating-never-expiring-facebook-page-access-token

Comment: but I just created one 2 days ago, is there any step you cannot process?

Comment: perhapse something has changed, I wlll try later